# double pointer c memory fault

Tags: c, pointers, char

Basically I need to write a split function and currently I need to know how to populate *substrings* with pointers to characters from *s*.

I have:

```
char *s = "--ab--c--";
char **substrings;
int split(char *s, int start, char sep, char **substrings, int max)
```

I don't know if definition for `*s` and `**substrings` are correct.

And I need to assign pointers to `*s` such as `**substrings` would contain:

```
{ "", "ab", "c", "" }
```

Formal definition of substrings

```
substrings - the array to populate with pointers to substrings of s
```

I don't know, I googled double pointed and couldn't figure out.

The size of `*s` is unknown and the number of `**substrings` is only know when program is executed.

I am new to C, but I think I need something like this:

```
substrings[0][0] = "";
substrings[1][0] = "a";
substrings[1][1] = "c";
substrings[2][0] = "c";
substrings[3][0] = "a";
```

Comment: In the code snippet You've just showed - You're not allocating any space neither for string pointers, nor for strings.

Comment: should I locate the memory in split function, I tried to allocate with malloc but got memory fault (core dumped)

Comment: so, could You show us, what actually have You tried, please?
Yes, it's on of the ways. Despite, not the best practise.

Comment: your first argument to split implies that it could be modified (non-const) but it seems as if you plan to pass 's' to it, that will not end well since s is defined as a string literal. you should declare it instead as `char s[] = "--ab--c--";`

Comment: Currently i have a code like this http://pastebin.com/heEe9P9U , i want to write a split function that if it finds char **sep** and next char isn't **sep** it would add s[i+1] char to substrings[which][0] if there is more than one character until next occurrence of **sep** if would add substrings[which][1] and so one

Answer (score 1):

It is unclear what the semantics your `split()` routine is but I 'm guessing that your `substrings` should be an *array* of pointers:

```
#define MAX_TOKENS  16 /* for example */
char* substrings[MAX_TOKENS];

split(s, ..., substrings, MAX_TOKENS);
```

Comment: so you are saying that the size should be preset aka MAX_TOKENS before compiling the program, it cannot be passed from stdin or file?

Comment: It can be, of course, but you will have to allocate _an array of pointers_ of a given size then. In many cases, when you are confident that number of tokens is limited it's easier to just have a fixed maximum size.

Answer (score 0):

At runtime, you know that you cannot have more substrings than you have characters in s. Thus, you can calloc enough space for that many substrings and only use the space you need.

```
  #include <stdlib.h>
  #include <string.h>

  char** substrings = (char**)calloc(strlen(s), sizeof(char));
  if (substrings == NULL) exit(1);

  // Split here
```

At this point, you have a data structure which holds pointers for strlen(s) strings. When you split your string, you will iterate through these pointers and assign each pointer to the new substring you have found.

Answer (score 0):

As you don't know number of substrings or size of every substring in advance, I would suggest to use `calloc` taking into account worst case, this is:

```
substrings = calloc(strlen(s), strlen(s)*sizeof(char));
```

`sizeof(char)` should be 1 but I included it just for didactic reasons.

About best way to implement `split` function, I think the best solution would be using `strchr`, it would be something similar to:

```
int split(char *s, int start, char sep, char **substrings, int max)
{
    char *old, *sp;
    int i=0;
    old=s;

    sp=strchr(old,sep);    
    while (sp!=NULL && i < max)
    {
        if(0 < (sp-old))
            strncpy(substrings+i++, old, sp - old);
        old = sp+1;
        sp=strchr(old,sep);
    }

    // Last sub string
    if(0 < (s+strlen(s)-old))
        strncpy(substrings+i++, old, s+strlen(s)-old);

    return i;
}
```

For your proposed input, this solution would dump an array containing: `{"ab","c"}`.

I assumed that `max` defines maximum allowed number of substrings and that every element in `substrings` has space enough to store corresponding substring (both conditions fulfilled with previously proposed `calloc`).